# Not possible to assign a task sometimes

Tags: profile, tasks

[image]I have one colleague who cannot always assign task, this is strange as her profile gives her the right to modify all accounts. Sometimes she can and sometimes she can't.
So I don't know where to find what is blocking.

Thanks for your support

Comment: My colleague just gave me a specific info, this is happening with one salesrep only, but this sales rep has the same profile and role and other sales reps for which she can assign a task

Comment: Check that the user has the appropriate level of access on Tasks

Comment: She has edit tasks permission, so I don't know why she cannot assign a task to only one colleague and she can for others

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Check if there's are any process builders, flows or Apex triggers that may be changing the task or processing other objects that that the user doesn't have permissions for.

Answer (score 2):

I see two possibilities:

1.) **Though she has access to edit some tasks, she does not have access to edit all tasks.** Sharing rules for Tasks and Events are configured in 'Sharing Settings' under the 'Activities' object. If your Organization-Wide Defaults for Activities is set to 'Controlled by Parent,' then a user must have access to edit the parent record in order to edit the related Task. In that case, check what record the tasks in question are related to and validate your colleague's edit permissions on that object. She could have different access to tasks based on the different records they are related to. [OWD Salesforce Help Article.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sharing_model_fields.htm&type=5)

2.) **She may have access to the User records of some sales reps, but not others.** This seems less likely, but if your Organization-Wide Default for Users is set to Private, then there must be sharing rules in place to grant access to Users. In this case the criteria on the sharing rules may be missing the one sales rep while including the others, even though they have the same profile and role. [Salesforce Help article that mentions this error.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000324944&type=1)

Comment: Ok thanks for this explanation. Here is what I have in activities : Object : activity - Default Internal access : private - default external access : private - grant access using hierarchies is ticked. So is it here I need to make a modification or not?

Comment: Since the OWD for Activities is set to 'Private', your colleague will only be able to edit Tasks that she owns or that are owned by people below her in the role hierarchy. Related Question [HERE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/183417). That could explain what you're seeing.

Comment: I get it, but i might say it does not seem correct, she can add tasks to other sales rep, which have the same role

Comment: Is she above them in the role hierarchy?